# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**. How to fix it.

```
$(window).load(function() {
   document.getElementById("id_city").innerHTML = ('<option>Select a City</option>');
   var selected_state = $('#id_state').val();
   var selected_city = $('#selected_city').val();
   var data = 'state='+selected_state  + '&selected_city='+selected_city; 
   var url = $('#url').val();
   $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:url,
     data:data,    // multiple data sent using ajax
     success: function (response) {
     document.getElementById("id_city").innerHTML=response;
    } 
  });  
});
```

Comment: be insure `id_city` is correct and element rendered on page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means in this line:

```
document.getElementById("id_city").innerHTML
```

you have

```
document.getElementById("id_city") = null
```

Please make sure you have any markup with id parameters set to "id_city"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are having an element with that id on the page. If possible please share the HTML for better result.

Example: `<select id="id_city"></select>`

Answer (score 1):

The error line is
document.getElementById("id_city").innerHTML 
and the reason could be

- the element not in html
- the script is called before the element is bound to html

try placing the script at the bottom of the page

Comment: If the script called is within `$(window).load()`, the position of the script on the page shouldn't matter, no?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jquery method`

```
$("#id_city").html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("id_city").innerHTML=response;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("id_city").html(response);
```

or

```
$('#id_city').html(response);
```

Comment: second one wont work since You apply jquery method on non jquery object

Comment: Both solutions wouldn't work. It seems that the element with the ID "id_city" cannot be found.

Comment: Both solutions are correct. There maybe an error with the selector

Comment: .html is part of jQuery and cannot be used on elements returned by getElementById, so no, they're not both correct